# Dictation disables f8 play/pause hotkey

Tags: keyboard, audio, voice-dictation

I'm trying to use dictation in order to dictate into a text editor a recording that I listen in a headset - played by VLC.

There's a big problem with the fact that, when dictation is running, the f8 play/pause hotkey is not functioning (in a Macbook Air).

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Does alt + F8 work?

Comment: @Robuust - No, but I have found that the problem is in fact with VLC and not with dictation. Dictation can in fact pause the player when it is started with the Fn key and un-pause it when it is stopped (double-click Fn key). But it works in this way with iTunes, bit not with VLC. This is an answer here, I think.

Comment: my question is a duplicate of [this one](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/110839/61618) - but very partial, because that one doesn't discriminate between media players and asks for a different thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that the problem is in fact with the way Dictation can or cannot work with VLC and other media players, except iTunes (I have also tried Clementine and MPlayerX).

**Dictation pauses iTunes when it is started with the Fn key and un-pauses it when it is stopped (double-click Fn key)** - a great feature, which doesn't seem to work with VLC.

The way the Fn key is meant in Dictation (pausing the player) is not the problem, but rather the solution to what I need Dictation for. It provides Fn key as an alternate and better solution to the pause/play media key. But I will have to use it only with iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

As noted:

- The <kbd>fn</kbd>-key can be pressed to pause the Dictation.
- To stop pausing you can double-press <kbd>fn</kbd>.

Comment: I know that, and that also pauses iTunes when dictation is started and un-pauses it when dictation is stopped/paused. This is a great solution itself for what I need, only that doesn't work with VLC as far as I can tell. Can you verify it with VLC?