# Prevent dictation from muting audio on Catalina

Tags: macos, audio, catalina, voice-dictation

When I start dictation (keybound to two right commands) all audio I am listening gets muted.

How do I stop that? I would like all audio to keep playing.

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/123268/150109) doesn't work for me on macOS 10.15.2, and [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/287619/150109) points to an option in Accessibility preferences that I guess doesn't exist anymore.