# Stop macOS muting while using dictation

Tags: macos, catalina, voice-dictation

When I use dictation on my MacBook Pro 2015 w/ Retina Display, running macOS Catalina 10.15.2, the system-wide audio all mutes while dictation is listening.

How do I prevent this?

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/123268/150109) from 2014 doesn't seem to work for me.