# CATALINA: Override automatic mute triggered by Dictation

Tags: catalina, defaults, voice-dictation, soundflower, macos

## PROBLEM

[Transcription Step 2 Instructions](https://medium.com/be-a-better-journalist/using-apple-s-dictation-tools-to-transcribe-audio-b1d992eabd27) indicates:

> When you’re running Dictation, your computer automatically mutes all
> audio that’s playing. To override this, you’ll need to run two
> commands in Terminal

I have performed the write-commands and read-commands:

```
user@users-Mac-mini ~ % defaults write com.apple.SpeechRecognitionCore AllowAudioDucking -bool NO
user@users-Mac-mini ~ % defaults read com.apple.SpeechRecognitionCore
```

> {
> AllowAudioDucking = 0; }

```
user@users-Mac-mini ~ % defaults write com.apple.speech.recognition.AppleSpeechRecognition.prefs DictationIMAllowAudioDucking -bool NO
user@users-Mac-mini ~ % defaults read com.apple.speech.recognition.AppleSpeechRecognition.prefs
```

> {
> DictationIMAllowAudioDucking = 0;
> DictationIMCorrectionCount = 0;
> DictationIMIntroMessagePresented = 1;
> DictationIMLastDictationDate = "619237426.7170759";
> DictationIMMessageTracesSinceLastReport = 4;
> DictationIMSensedMicActivityState = 1;
> DictationIMSensedMicIdentifier = "SoundflowerEngine:0";
> "DictationIMUpgradedTo10_15" = 1; }

## RESEARCH \ REFERENCES

1. [How to keep sound from muting while using dictation?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110839/how-to-keep-sound-from-muting-while-using-dictation)
2. Anyone: please to add relevant links

## OBSERVATIONS

Reference 1 (above) indicates BASH commands overrides mute trigger in Mojave in 10.14.1

Audio drives the input level meter as expected:

[image]

A speech audio file is started.  The text editor is opened: when Dictation is invoked, the input level meter goes dead (audio player automatically muted).

## QUESTIONS

What can be done to diagnose why the BASH commands were not effective in disable automatic mute?

Comment: I was having the same issue but I wasn't aware of the audio muting commands. When I set it up I found that if I left the Dictation page of Preferences the muting issue happened. If I stayed there, it didn't! At the time I had my MBP connected to the TV via HDMI and I was using it like this for weeks. The TV is now gone and I had to restart my mac and my little trick isnt working nor are your anti-muting commands. :(  I am sharing this in case it triggers something for someone...